# Template ignores [[nodiscard]] attribute

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, c++17

When applied to a function, the [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute encourages the compiler to issue a warning if it is used in a discarded expression other than a cast to `void`. Example:

```
[[nodiscard]] int callable_return_not_discardable(int n)
{ return n; }

int main()
{
    callable_return_not_discardable(0); // warning/error:
        // ignoring return value of 'int callable_return_not_discardable(int)',
        // declared with attribute nodiscard [-Wunused-result]
    (void) callable_return_not_discardable(0); // OK
}
```

Live demo on [gcc-8](https://godbolt.org/z/VE6DoN) and [clang-7](https://godbolt.org/z/EUmwCr).

---

This is nice and useful, until an additional indirection layer is added: templates:

```
template<class Callable>
void invoke_with_answer(Callable&& callable)
{ callable(42); }

[[nodiscard]] int callable_return_not_discardable(int n)
{ return n; }

int main()
{
    invoke_with_answer(callable_return_not_discardable); // OK
}
```

Live demo on [gcc-8](https://godbolt.org/z/44aZwq) and [clang-7](https://godbolt.org/z/QdQk1h).

My question is then:
**Is it a missing feature, a consequence of what templates are or should clang and gcc be fixed to issue a warning here?**

Comment: It has nothing to do with this being a template. If you replace your first line with `using Callable = int(int);`, you obtain exactly the same behavior. _The behavior is a consequence (cf. StoryTellers answer) of what function pointers are._

Comment: @Handy Hi. Replying in the comment section is generally frowned upon. If you think you can improve an answer, suggest an edit or answer yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[[nodiscard]]` is not part of a function's signature or type, and not at all preserved when said function is converted to a pointer or bound to a reference. Which is exactly what your example does.

The template, for all intents and purposes cannot "see" the attribute.

Comment: @You beat me to the punch, so I might as well nitpick the things I was verifying :)

Comment: Hmm, the standard has stuff like "attributes appertain to the function type". Doesn't this mean that the attribute information is not lost?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - An attribute has to be applicable to a function's type for that to hold. And `[[nodiscard]]` simply isn't. It might be just a oversight.

Answer (score 5):

As [explained by StorryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391959/5470596), `[[nodiscard]]` is not part of a function's signature or type, this is why that information is lost in the context of the template body.

A solution to get that warning propagated would be to add the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to the return **type** of that function:

```
template<class Callable>
void invoke_with_answer(Callable&& callable)
{ callable(42); } // warning

struct [[nodiscard]] Int { int value; };

Int callable_return_not_discardable(int n)
{ return {n}; }

int main()
{
    invoke_with_answer(callable_return_not_discardable); // note
}
```

[Live demo on gcc-8](https://godbolt.org/z/VDJEVU)

Comment: `enum [[nodiscard]] Int : int{};` is also an option for integral types. At least you get conversions to an `int` without too much fuss.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's true :) I'll let it as-is since it's not the point, but true ^^.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Is it? I don't quite get it, the enumeration is empty so any introspection tool/library would/should report all integers as not being part of the enumerated values. Won't this create more problems ?

Comment: @LorahAttkins - All integers of the underlying type are part of the enumeration. Enumerators are just named constants in the range (and they may be omitted entirely). It's not something esoteric, seeing as that's exactly how `std::byte` is defined (though as a scoped enumeration). Introspection tools are geared with heuristics for certain use cases, but are not free of false warnings.